# IdentityServer3 supported browsers

Tags: identityserver3

I am trying to find the official documentation for the supported browser list for IdentityServer3.   Does anyone know a link or such?  I have been crawling the official documentation and have not found a full list as of yet.. Hopefully, I have just over looked it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean the default views, they utilize the following js libs - so you're better off the browser support for these:

[=> source code, external js libs](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/tree/master/source/Core/Services/DefaultViewService/HttpAssets/libs)

- Angular 1.3.1
- Boostrap 3.0.3
- jQuery 1.11

When that is said, all views can be overriden and implemented by you - so you can decide yourself what your browser support level is.

To quote Brock Allen on what's the intended default browser support

> We don't support deprecated browsers. IIRC we agreed to IE9 and above. In fact much of the login or consent pages won't work for you if you're in IE7 I'd imagine.

[=> source of quote](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/778#issuecomment-70495469)

Comment: Thanks for the link and such.. Much appreciated.